# Can I merge multiple TFS Site Collections into one?

Tags: site-collection, tfs

I apologize if this question makes no sense but I'm struggling to figure out how SharePoint and TFS interact, so my terminology might be all wrong.

I'm managing a small TFS2010  deployment, a single project collection with 8 projects in it. It's been upgraded from TFS2005 -> TFS2008 -> TFS2010, and brought all the SharePoint site information with it.

What I have ended up with, once everything had settled, is a SharePoint site with (I think) 6 site collections:

```
/
/sites/Project1
/sites/Project2
/sites/Project3
/sites/Project4
/sites/TeamProjectCollection
```

The four projects that were created **after** the upgrade to TFS2010 and SharePoint Foundation are all found as sub-sites under /sites/TeamProjectCollection, but the four projects that were migrated in from TFS2005/SharePoint 2.0 are listed as their own site collection.

This is causing me several headaches:

- I have to manage user accounts/permissions separately, even though 50% of the users have the same permissions across all sites
- I have to go to 5 different places to manage site settings instead of one.
- Some projects show up as tabs on the TeamProjectCollection site and others don't, which annoys me and confuses some users.

Is there a way to take the single top-level site for each of those site collections and make it into a sub-site?

Comment: By the way, I noticed an edit to fix my version number. The Sharepoint product I have installed is called "Windows Sharepoint Services 3.0"... is that the same thing as Sharepoint Foundation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save needed sites as templates with content and then recreate them as subsites on you root site collection. The content will be migrated, but the permissions will require customization. Also there is migration tools that can migrate sites from one site collection to other.

Comment: I had not noticed before that TFS2010 lets you "repoint" the project portal URL after the project has been created (I'm pretty sure TFS2005/2008 didn't let you do that), so doing this was pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

Am sorry but as far as i know ther's no possibility to merge project collections cause of possible conflicts with duplicate item ids (of tasks, builds, tests.... ). You can only split a existing Site Collection into 2 or more.

Answer (score 0):

For merging the TFS projects itself, there's a [tool on CodePlex](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/), this is NOT possible out of the box (conflicting IDs etc).

If you want to move the subsites, you'll have to find a way to "rewire" them in TFS to the new location so that all links still work. For a guide on integrating both SharePoint 2010 and TFS 2010, you can use [this article](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/integrate-sharepoint-2010-with-team-foundation-server-2010/). Halfway down is the part you need to set the actual wiring between both environments.